# My rear disc brake became slippery

Tags: motorcycle, brakes

Yesterday i Lubed my chain and Sprocket. On the other side there was rear brake disc. So while spraying on chain and sprocket some oil through spray went on to disc. Now after that brake not working. My guess is, it has became slippery.

Now how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest cleaning the brake disc with a degreaser and replace the rear brake pads.

Comment: Cleaning disc only worked for me. I cleaned it using water and dish washing soap to remove oil and now it is working fine. and i even completed 350km long trip after that. Thanks for your replies...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pads from the brake caliper and clean them with copious amounts of brake cleaner - you may want to abrade the surface a little with some emery paper first.

Prepare the disc surface again with some emery paper then clean them with brake cleaner.

If the brake still feels "slippery" after you may have to repeat the disc cleaning and use new brake pads.

Comment: I don't agree that "cleaning them" is the safest option, but your brakes, your life, your choice.

Comment: I would replace them too, I should have said replace them, initially but also that they could attempt to clean them at their own peril...

Comment: brake cleaner, rags, sanding, repeat multiple times for pads, install, test, depending on pads type prepare for replacing pads. brake cleaner with clean rags should be enough for disk.

Comment: Cleaning disc only worked for me. I cleaned it using water and dish washing soap to remove oil and now it is working fine. Thanks for your replies...